# How to close the tab it contains some url ("www.xyz.com") in java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

In my browser, i opened number of tabs, in one tab i opened my website **(like www.aaa.com)**, in my website has one hyperlink to open another website **(like www.xyz.com)**. Now i am ready to LOGOUT my website, in this time my requirement is whenever i signedout my website, the www.xyz.com tab also closed, How to do it, i search a lot in google but i didn't get any relative answer. I am using java technologies. Please any one help me .

**Thanks & Regards**

Chakri

Comment: as a policy of security for browsers, you can not do that, it wouldn't made sense if you could

Comment: @Amin Jafari, first i think it is possible, after that i know its impossible, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have control of other tabs from your website's tab. Otherwise I can rule the internet.

You may better look into [**iframes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: @suresh atta, there is any another possibility to do it ?